# PHP PNG Transparency

Tags: php, png, transparency

I have a code which is converting PNG to PNG (the PNG is originally bad! There is no transparency) so my task is to restore the transpareny.

```
$image = imageCreateFromPng("./kep.png");
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($image, $background);
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image,NULL);
```

This is my code but not working. I receive a black backgrounded picture. I have googled hours but nothing helped.

The original PNG has BLACK color when i open it with Photoshop. I want to make a code which make a good transparent png from the bad png.

(If i open the bad png with gimp, then save as png the transparency is good, but i need something automatically.)

What i missed? 
Thanks!

Comment: Mind that browsers often apply their own background for transparent images. Firefox does this `url("chrome://global/skin/media/imagedoc-lightnoise.png") repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(0, 0%, 90%)` so the background color appears differently. Also, from my experience with photo editors, transparent images had black background if I dragged them onto editor, but they were transparent when I manually opened them in the editor.

Comment: Thanks, really the browser applied it. But the problem is still here, i want to restore the transparency of the image somehow :/ (When i opened it manually, the same problem)